# How to find which module defines an annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse-jee

[image]

From the IDE, or from the command line, how can I reverse-look up which module defines a particular annotation?

For example, in the attached screenshot, how can I check which dependency module contains the definition of `@NotFound`. (Of course, this is an example. Actual issue is when I'm reading a code that has 50 dependency at the top of the file and tons of various annotation being used). Is there an easy way find the actual module?

Comment: In the IDE usually ctrl-LeftMouseClick (IntelliJ) will bring you to the file defining the annotation. Should be making out what module it is by the file location

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using IntelliJ IDEA. If so, you can search for text occurrences through the whole project or through specific module by using [search everywhere feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the search window.

[image]